# Select a particular record from identical records in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+
| type    | city    | name                                    |
+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+
| cricket | kolkata | Khadim's Ashok Malhotra Cricket Academy |
| cricket | kolkata | Calcutta Cricket Coaching Center (C4)   |
| cricket | kolkata | Sambaran Banerjee Cricket academy       |
| cricket | kolkata | Bournvita cricket acadamemy of arun lal |
| cricket | kolkata | friends of the stadium                  |
| cricket | kolkata | pankaj roy cricket academy              |
| cricket | kolkata | sunil gavaskar cricket foundation       |
| cricket | kolkata | castlewood india                        |
| cricket | kolkata | GK sports                               |
| cricket | kolkata | NULL                                    |
| cricket | kolkata | NULL                                    |
| cricket | kolkata | NULL                                    |
| cricket | kolkata | NULL                                    |
| cricket | kolkata | NULL                                    |
| cricket | kolkata | NULL                                    |
+---------+---------+-----------------------------------------+
```

I want to give different names instead of `NULL`, how can I do this?

Comment: If you have such as question then your database table is poorly designed. How come you have many records with the same key? This can be acceptable only for "dump" non-relational tables like event logs etc... where table is used just as a file-access convenience. But in a relational database design this is a no-no. Please revise your logical design and then physical DDL for table, add a key and purge duplicate meaningless rows

Comment: what do you want instead of `null`? what is your goal here?

Answer (score 0):

Try `IFNULL`

```
Select IFNULL(name,'Jon Smith') as name from myTable
```

If you want the institute's name when the value in name is null
you can::

```
Select IFNULL(name,institute) as name from myTable
```

Comment: thanks for answering but here, now i am getting 'jon smith' in place of null. is there any way to insert different names for different records?

Comment: Any example what you want, from your table?

Comment: @user1937032 your question is very unclear. edit the question and write what you want the end result to be so we can help you :)

Comment: in the place of null i want different institutes names like B. Dasgupta & co,Kolkata Cricket Coaching Centre, jp cricket institute, .....

Comment: are the institute's name a column in the table, or you want to put it randomly

Comment: have added a query, please check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also :

Starting with `name`

```
select * from table_name where name like "Cricket%"
```

contains any where

```
select * from table_name where name like "%Cricket%"
```

ends with

```
select * from table_name where name like "%Cricket"
```